# Yii: How can I define data parameters in ajaxLink using JS?

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I'm working with a Yii ajaxLink:

```
echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
'Toggle',
Yii::app()->createUrl('Tweet/toggleTag'),
array(
    'type' => 'POST',
    ...
    'data' => array('tagID'=>$data->tagID)
    ...
```

What I want to do is make the link toggle the tag (client and server side). I have a class that marks the element, but I'm not sure how to get access to that and pass it to the data parameter via Yii.

The link gets a 'hasTag' class when it has a tag.

I could just check if the tag is enabled on the server, but that doesn't seem like the right answer to me.

How can I toggle the tag based on its client side state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps not the best answer, but it works...

I was able to use beforeSend to alter the data parameter:

```
'beforeSend'=>"function(){
    var myData = <whatever logic needs to be executed>;
    this.data += '&hasTag='+myData;
}",
```

Comment: You'll need to be more specific.

Comment: nothing gets added to `this.data` i had to append to `this.url`

Comment: Well it has been three years since this answer was posted. I suppose Yii might have changed. If so your comment should help anyone else who wanders by!